# Why does Python allow mentioning a method without calling it?

Tags: python

I had some trouble finding my error: I had written

```
myfile.close
```

instead of

```
myfile.close()
```

I am surprised and somewhat unhappy that python did not object; how come? BTW the file was NOT closed.
(python 2.7 on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

In python methods are first class objects, you can write something like that:

```
my_close = myfile.close
my_close()
```

Since expressions don't have to be assigned to some variable

```
2 + 3
```

a simple

```
myfile.close
```

is valid, too.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `myfile.close` returns a method.

If you do `print(myfile.close)` you will get an output like:

```
<built-in method close of file object at 0x7fb672e0f540>
```

Answer (score 1):

Python file object has built-in method `close()` to handle file object. 
In your case `myfile.close` will return the method object reference but it is not being called.

This example will may be helpful to understand this:

```
>>> def test():
...     print 'test print'
... 
>>> a = test
>>> print(a)
<function test at 0x7f6ff1f6ab90>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`myfile.close` is a member function of a file-like object. Your code just 'mentions' this function, but doesn't call it (this is why the file wasn't closed).

It's the same as doing this:

```
a = 5
a # OK but does nothing

def test():
    return 256
test # also not an error, but useless in this case
```

Now, you may say, why even allow this if it's totally useless? Well, not quite. With this you can pass functions as arguments to other functions, for example.

```
def MyMap(function, iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        yield function(x)

print(list(MyMap(str, range(5))))
```

Answer (score 1):

`fp.close` is method of file object.

```
>>> fp.close
<built-in method close of file object at 0xb749c1d8>
```

`fp.close()` is method call by using `()`

```
>>> fp.close()
```

You can understand in more details by following Demo.

We define `test` function and we is `test` and `test()` to see difference.

```
>>> def test():
...   return 1
... 

>>> test
<function test at 0xb742bb54>

>>> test()
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not throw an error because you don't have to assign a name to the result of an expression (edit: or statement). Python allows this because it could be that you only need the expression/statement for some sort of side effect but not the actual return value.

This is often seen when advancing an iterator without assigning a name to the yielded object, i.e. just having a line

```
next(myiter, None)
```

in the code.

If you wanted expressions with no sideeffects like

```
1 + 1
```

or

```
myfile.close
```

to throw an error if there is no name assigned to the result (and therefore the expression is useless) Python would have to inspect each right hand side of an expression for possible sideeffects. Compared to the current behavior of just allowing these expressions, this seems needlessly expensive (and would also be very complex, if not impossible for every expression).

Consider how dynamic Python is. You could override what the `+` operator does to certain types at runtime.