# Variable Not Defined In If statement (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

In my program, I have a series of if statements defining the value of a variable depending on user input, however, later on when attempting to use the said variable, the program states it wasn't ever defined.

```
paint_colour = input("Choose Paint Colour (White, Red, Blue, Green): ")

if paint_colour.lower == "white":
    paint_price = 18.90
elif paint_colour.lower == "red":
    paint_price = 20.30)
elif paint_colour.lower == "blue":
    paint_price = 21.50
elif paint_colour.lower == "green":
    paint_price = 22.80

print(paint_price)
```

I can't figure out another way of doing this and wondered what the issue here is.
It's worth noting I did try this with an else statement at the end, however, this just led to the program always utilising whatever I had in there.

```
paint_colour = input("Choose Paint Colour (White, Red, Blue, Green): ")

if paint_colour.lower == "white":
    paint_price = 18.90
elif paint_colour.lower == "red":
    paint_price = 20.30
elif paint_colour.lower == "blue":
    paint_price = 21.50
elif paint_colour.lower == "green":
    paint_price = 22.80
else:
    paint_price = 0
```

Help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I reckon `lower` is a method. Not an attribute.

Comment: `lower` is a method, not a property - you should use `paint_colour.lower()` instead.

Comment: Currently none of your if/elif statements are True, so the else is needed. Also, what if the user enters "yellow"?

Comment: In your first approach if nothing matches  then `paint_price` isn't defined so when you try and access it later it's undefined. Another approach would be to define a default value before the conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to use `paint_colour.lower()` as `lower` is a method.

Since you're using `.lower` and in python, even though it's a method, doing `.lower` won't give you any error. You may find the reason for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174796/why-does-python-allow-mentioning-a-method-without-calling-it).

Hence whatever valid input you give, execution will not reach in any of the `if-else`. But in the end, you're trying to print out a variable which isn't initialized during the execution. Hence the error

A better version of your code would look like below

```
paint_colour = input("Choose Paint Colour (White, Red, Blue, Green): ")

if paint_colour.lower() == "white":
    paint_price = 18.90
elif paint_colour.lower() == "red":
    paint_price = 20.30
elif paint_colour.lower() == "blue":
    paint_price = 21.50
elif paint_colour.lower() == "green":
    paint_price = 22.80
else:
    paint_price = "Invalid input"

print(paint_price)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.lower` is not a property, but a `method`

That is, you need to call the method in order to get it work, otherwise, you will only get the function itself, not the result.

To give a brief example, let's look at what these codes return as a result:

```py
print("HELLO WORLD".lower())
# >>> hello world
```

```py
print("HELLO WORLD".lower)
# >>> <built-in method lower of str object at 0x7fe466f54f30>
```